# Why is my <rich:popupPanel> not working?

Tags: popup, richfaces, panel, final

I have the following code:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Adicionar BOM"
    onclick="#{rich:component('addBomModal')}.show()">
    <a4j:ajax event="click" immediate="true"
        oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('addBomModal')"
    render="addBomModal" />
</a4j:commandButton>
```

and

```
<h:form>
    <rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="true" resizeable="true"
        onmaskclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide()">
        // rest of popupPanel
    </rich:popupPanel>
</h:form>
```

The page is rendered but nothing happens when I click the button.

How can this be solved?

Thanks in advance,
gtludwig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many things going on. You first open the pop-up in onclick (button) and then open it again in oncomplete via older API (I'm not sure it was migrated to RichFaces 4). All you need is what you have in onclick, you don't need a4j:ajax.